# undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, comments, posts

I'm trying to create a way to have users comment on my posts. Currently I have All user posts showing up on my home page and then in the user profile only the current users posts. I would like to have it so that the comments appear only on the posts in the users profile. I tried to add a comment form in the user profile but I got an undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass error.

My comments_controller looks like

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
end
```

I have a partial (_comment_form.html.erb) that I am rendering in the user profile which looks like

```
<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

My Comment model looks like

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

My Post model looks like

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :content

 belongs_to :user

 validates :content, :presence => true
 validates :user_id, :presence => true
 validates :user, :presence => true
 validates :title, :presence => true

 has_many :comments

 default_scope :order => 'posts.created_at DESC'
end
```

My User Profile Looks like show.html.erb

```
<table class="profile" summary="Profile information">
  <tr>
    <td class="main">
    <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
    </h1>
    <% unless @user.posts.empty? %>
        <table class="posts" summary="User posts">
            <%= render @posts %>
            <%= render 'comments/comment_form' %>
        </table>    
    <% end %>
    </td>
    <td class="sidebar round">
  <strong>Name</strong> <%= @user.name %><br />
  <strong>URL</strong>  <%= link_to user_path(@user), @user %><br />
  <strong>Tasks</strong> <%= @user.posts.count %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that you haven't initialized `@post` in the `new` method of your controller and it's being used as `nil`. Always construct an empty model for your new form if it's practical:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Always provide explanation to the code you post as this will be needed for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Are you initializing the @post in the show action of your PostsController? That would be required because you are redirecting from the create action of your CommentsController.

Comment: Yeah I tried doing that and still it didn't change anything unless I did it wrong. I did   def show
    (at)post = Post.find(params[:post])
    (at)comments = (at)post.comments
  end

Comment: Did you add the show action handler in your PostsController or CommentsController? You need to add the action handler in the PostsController (if you have one)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= render @posts %>
```

This line should reference @post instead. Note the trailing s, compared to all the other references to it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see `log/development.log` to see where the error occurred? It wasn't clear from the question. But judging from your code, there are two possible locations:

1. `@comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])`
   here is unlikely because the last line of code is `Post.find` which will raise a `RecordNotFound` if the `id` is not found
2. `<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>`

This is very likely, can you do a `puts @post.inspect` and check your development.log to see if that is null. Assuming that it is null, you need to instantiate a `Post` object wherever you rendered `_comment_form.html.erb`